# File not found error when using web pack build in cordova app on android

Tags: android, cordova, webpack

I want to wrap a react based web app which gets build using webpack in a
cordova container for an Android device. I successfully built the
cordova app for iOS and everything worked fine. However, when building
for android, static resources like images and fonts that are required in
javascript using webpack's file-loader, aren't loaded correctly.
The web view tries to load all resources like an image from
`file:///android_asset/www/build/myImage.png`, but logs a file not found
error. If I link - for example - the same image directly in the
index.html via an image tag, the image is loaded correctly, but changing
the publicPath attribute in my webpack config file didn't work.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I would really love to know if you have resolved this.

Comment: Would also like to see a resolution to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

My brute force solution:

Pre-React Build: add "homepage": "./", to app’s package.json.

Post-React Build, and Pre-Cordova Run Android: in www/static/js, find/replace “static/media” with “android_asset/www/static/media” for all image/pdf files in the main###.js file (not the .map file).

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to add   "homepage": "/android_asset/www/" to package.json, it works perfectly with dynamic paths,